# Draw quart shape when clicked

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

This is my code:

```
@implementation myView2
{
BOOL _touchHasBegun;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
_touchHasBegun = YES;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
if (_touchHasBegun == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"fjnv");
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 225, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 255, 1);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(50, 50, 500, 500);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
}
}
```

I have also tried with a `UIButton` on top of the `UIView` and set the `CGRect` in the button action method. But that doesn't work. Nor does this code. What's wrong?

Comment: I think you need to add [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event] to properly keep the touch behavior.

Comment: Should I add it to the if statement?

Comment: @Kirualex Should I add it to the if-statement?

Comment: no just add it like this :
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
_touchHasBegun = YES;
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    _touchHasBegan = YES;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if(_touchHasBegan){
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 225, 1);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 255, 1);
        CGRect rectangle = self.bounds;
        CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! was the only problem in the if statement?

Comment: No, the main issue was that you have to call setNeedsDisplay to notify the system that you want it to call drawRect as soon as it's possible. You can check my answer (little checkmark) if it solved your problem by the way.